# Change value(s) in a pandas DataFrame which were selected from multiple column values

Tags: python, pandas

First post so please pardon my untactful way of asking this question.

I am working on a problem and I am having trouble changing values of a DataFrame after I have located the rows that fit certain criterias.

> data = pd.read_csv('students.csv')
>
> The indexes are: StudentId, Tuition, Scholarship, CreditScore, City,
>   Highschool

I am looking only for the students that have High School == 'x', and CreditScore == 'y', then change their Scholarship float from 0.0 to 8.5.

Please note that there are multiple Students with 0.0 Scholarship figures, and I am trying to change only the Scholarship values for students with both HighSchool=='x' and CreditScore=='y'.

The issue I'm encountering is that when I locate the rows that fit my criteria and try to change Scholarship values, pandas is only changing the value of what appears to be the COPY of the DataFrame. I would like to change the value of the DataFrame.

I've tried:

```
data[data[([Highschool]=='x') & ([CreditScore]=='y')]]['Scholarship'] = 8.5
data[data[([Highschool]=='x') & ([CreditScore]=='y')]]['Scholarship'].replace(0, 8.5, inplace=True)
```

However, after checking `data[data[([Highschool]=='x') & ([CreditScore]=='y')]]['Scholarship']`, the selected results for 'Scholarship' still show 0.0.

What better method may I change the values for the columns that fit the search criteria?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use `loc`

```
data.loc[(data['Highschool']=='x') & (data['CreditScore']=='y'), 'Scholarship'] = 8.5
```

Or equivalently

```
hs = data.Highschool == 'x'
cs = data.CreditScore == 'y'
data.loc[hs & cs, 'Scholarship'] = 8.5
```

---

***demonstration***

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
data = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Highschool=np.random.choice(('x', 'y', 'z'), 20),
        CreditScore=np.random.choice(('y', 'n'), 20),
        Scholarship=np.zeros(20)
    ))

data.loc[
    (data['Highschool']=='x') & 
    (data['CreditScore']=='y'),
    'Scholarship'] = 8.5

print(data)

   CreditScore Highschool  Scholarship
0            y          x          8.5
1            n          z          0.0
2            n          z          0.0
3            n          z          0.0
4            n          z          0.0
5            y          y          0.0
6            y          y          0.0
7            y          z          0.0
8            y          x          8.5
9            y          z          0.0
10           n          x          0.0
11           n          z          0.0
12           n          x          0.0
13           n          x          0.0
14           n          z          0.0
15           y          x          8.5
16           n          z          0.0
17           n          z          0.0
18           n          x          0.0
19           y          y          0.0
```

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared! This was the precise way I was looking to make the changes. It appears that data[data[([Highschool]=='x') & ([CreditScore]=='y')]]['Scholarship'] is only creating a copy of the dataframe, whereas 
data.loc[(data['Highschool']=='x') & (data['CreditScore']=='y'), 'Scholarship'] is calling the column 'Scholarship' from the DataFrame where indexes Highschool and CreditScore match the criteria. If I misunderstand, please let me know. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
def change_grade(x):
    ...:     if x[0] == 'x' and x[1] == 'y':
    ...:         return x[2] + 8.5
    ...:     else:
    ...:         pass
```

0 is the column index of 'Highschool', 1 is the index of 'CreditScore', and 2 is the index of 'Scholarship'

```
df['Scholarship'] = df.apply(change_grade, axis = 1)
```

Although, @piRSquared has suggested a far more eloquent one liner as always.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry I appreciate your input. I was looking for a way other than to create a function to change the values for said columns, although I agree that there are times when a function has its advantages. Have a great day.